# FileSystemWatcher - Create and Rename C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm currently working on a feeder app which looks for new files added and print me the name of it. But when I create a new file, the file name is printed immediately on the console. It is not waiting till I rename the newly created file. How can I do this?

Below are my settings. I didnt use `watcher.Renamed+=OnRenamed` because when I rename the any other file which is in the folder it is printing on the console. But my requirement is only show the list of newly created files.

```
 watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(folderPath);
 watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
 watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
 watcher.Filter = "*.*";
 watcher.Created += OnCreated;
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (probably) that you're going into windows explorer, right clicking and selecting new -> file type. When you do that, windows immediately creates the file with a default name like `New Text Document.txt` and give you an opportunity to rename it. This rename that follows in indistinguishable from any other rename so you have 2 options.

1. Stop creating files like that, rather create files by opening a text editor (or whatever app you're using word, excel etc) create a new file in the app and save it with the correct name. That will create the file with the name you expect.
2. Change your code to cater for file renames.

Comment: Thanks CamW :) I thought filewatcher will handle that situation also. So was trying with creating files in the folder itself.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate that MS decided to build windows explorer that way instead of waiting until after the user had renamed the file before actually creating it on disk.

Comment: Hi Cam. I have another doubt. I'm facing a problem while moving a set of documents to the folder. for eg: When I insert/move some 30 documents to the folder on which filewatcher is running, It is not showing all the filenames when I print. But when I keep a break point, then its working. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: @ASN, I've never had a problem with the FileSystemWatcher not "seeing" a change that was made. I would need to see the code and output that you're seeing when you run the app. Please create a new question, listing your code, the console output when you just copy the files and the console output when you copy with a breakpoint and I'll have a look. You can post a link to the question here if you like.

Comment: Please have a look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473806/filesystemwatcher-with-documents-indexing-as-attachments/37474483#37474483

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch for rename due to how file explorer in Windows handles creation of new files (via New->Text Document shortcut, for instance).

You can keep track of the full path of added files via a `HashSet<string>` object, and change your monitoring logic as follows:

When a file is *created*, check its size. You can use [`FileInfo.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx) to do that. If it's zero bytes, ignore the event. Otherwise, add it to the `HashSet` (duplicates will be ignored automatically).

When a file is *renamed*, check old full path and name and remove it from the `HashSet` if it's there; add the new full path and name to the `HashSet` regardless of size.

This should catch all new files and ignore "New Text Document" style objects.