# FileSystemwatcher with Documents Indexing as Attachments

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to reproduce a console application which watches a folder and any new additions of documents to the folder are to be Indexed to ES .

It is working fine If I move/add 3-4 documents at a time and able to index. But if I move around 30 documents at a time, It is not indexing all the documents, instead indexing only one. But If I run the code with break points , then even 30 documents are also getting indexed. 
Can some one help me in solving this.

```
 static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Created: Path: {0}, \n Name: {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name);
            Indexdoc(e.FullPath);
        }
```

If I dont call the Indexdoc(e.FullPath) method in the above code and instead print the changes, it is showing all the filenames added perfectly. so there is no problem with the filesystemwatcher. I think indexing documents is taking time to generate response and come back to onCreated method.

```
    public static void Indexdoc(string newFilePath)
            {
                List<Document> list = new List<Document>(); //list of Document class objects
                List<string> filesList = new List<string>(); //list of files in the path received on method call
                string path = string.Empty;

                client = ConfigSettings.connection();

                if (newFilePath == null) //for FULL Indexing
                {
                   //some code here
                }
                else //for new files indexing
                {
                    filesList.Add(newFilePath); //adds only one file everytime the method is called.
                    //the newFilePath will be of type C:/Documents/abc.txt
                }

                try
                {
                    foreach (string file in filesList)
                    {
                        Attachment attach = new Attachment
                        {
                            Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                            Content = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(file)),
                            ContentType = Path.GetExtension(file)
                        };

                        var doc = new Document()
                        {
                            Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                            FilePath = Path.GetFullPath(file), //added to get the path of the file
                            File = attach
                        };

                        list.Add(doc);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                }

                var response = client.IndexMany(list, "trial");
            }
```

Can some one help me in solving this.

TIA

Comment: Have the `OnCreated` event handler add the document names to a queue, and have a background thread running that services the queue, removing names and indexing them.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks Jim. I never worked on threads. Can you help me how can I do that. Is it something like this?(http://www.dotnetperls.com/queue) TIA

Answer (score 1):

First, create a queue that you'll use to put the information in. This is at class scope:

```
private BlockingCollection<string> CreatedQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
```

At startup, you want to create a `Task` that watches that queue for changes:

```
var queueProcessor = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessQueue, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Your `OnCreated` event handler looks like this:

```
static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File Created: Path: {0}, \n Name: {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name);
    CreatedQueue.Add(e.FullPath);
}
```

And the `ProcessQueue` method looks like this:

```
void ProcessQueue()
{
    foreach (var fileName in CreatedQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Indexdoc(fileName);
    }
}
```

The `ProcessQueue` method will continue removing items from the queue (or waiting for items to be added, so that it can remove them) until the queue is marked as completed. That is, you say you're done adding items and the queue is empty. So when you shut down, you have to call `CompleteAdding`, and then make sure the queue is empty before you exit. To do that, your main program does this:

```
// Tell the queue that no more items will be added
CreatedQueue.CompleteAdding();

// Wait for the task to complete
queueProcessor.Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Can you please check  and let me know if the below code posted by me is correct. I've just made modifications based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking input from users to exit the application. Should I add these codes below there?

```
// Tell the queue that no more items will be added
CreatedQueue.CompleteAdding();

// Wait for the task to complete
queueProcessor.Wait();
```

This is the code I modified.

```
    public class FileWatcher
    {
        public static ElasticClient client;
        public static FileSystemWatcher watcher;
        public static BlockingCollection<string> CreatedQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var queueProcessor = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessQueue(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            watch();

        }

        public static void watch()
        {
            folderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["location"];


            try
            {
                watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                watcher.Path = folderPath;

                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                watcher.Filter = "*.*";


                watcher.Created += OnCreated;

                Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************************");
                // Wait for user to quit program.
                Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the watcher application at any point of time.");
                Console.WriteLine();

                //Make an infinite loop till 'q' is pressed.
                while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A Exception Occurred :" + e);
            }

            catch (Exception oe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Exception Occurred :" + oe);
            }
        }

        static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Created: Path: {0}, \n Name: {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name);
            CreatedQueue.Add(e.FullPath);
        }

        public static void ProcessQueue()
        {
            foreach (var fileName in CreatedQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Indexdoc(fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Indexdoc(string newFilePath)
    {}
```

Comment: I tried it. When i added 30 files, it is indexing only 20 of them and after that  VS goes not responding mode. Even the exit input 'q' is not working.  Where can I add the createdqueue.completeadding method?

Comment: put it under `while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;`

Comment: actually, put it under `watch()` in main, logically the same but better structured. also include `queueProcessor.Wait();` under `CreatedQueue.CompleteAdding();` as indicated by Jim

Comment: @CamW Thanks cam. will add these two statements under watch() in the main()  and try. (But now, I have a problem with the IDE i suppose. It this throwing SystemOutofMemory Exception for 50 documents)
`public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var queueProcessor = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessQueue(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            watch();
CreatedQueue.CompleteAdding();
queueProcessor.Wait()

        }`

Comment: @CamW Hi Cam, I tried with your code. Now it is able to index everything. First it is printing all the names and then slowly indexing in queue. But the problem is the exit code is not working and the IDE went to not responding mode when i closed the console by clicking on X

Comment: @CamW Hi Cam. I have a problem now. When a file is open or being modified, how can I ignore it and take the previous version of the file and go ahead?

Comment: So the FileSystemWatcher will only provide you with a filename after the file is saved. Once that file has been overwritten, there's no way to get back the previous version. If you want some sort of version history, you would need to build it yourself. Perhaps by copying file versions into a separate folder or database and versioning them.

Comment: not exactly ignore it but ignore the fact that it is opened and take the document. something like [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/check-for-new-files-addition-and-index-them-as-an-attachment/49626)